# How do I execute a python script within another and have it return a list object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script `test.py` and I want it to execute another script `this_other_script.py` which will return a list object. `test.py` looks like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    someValue = this_other_script

    print(len(someValue))
```

`this_other_script.py` looks like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [a,b,c,d]
    return(data)
```

When I run `test.py` I receive an error of `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`.

If this is due to program scope I would have thought it would be OK for the calling program to be given a return value from a program it is calling. I wouldn't expect for `this_other_script` to access a value of a variable not given to it by `test.py` so I'm not sure why this error is displayed.

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know: you have a `return` statement that is not inside a function. What are you not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternative answer:

in test.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import this_other_script
    someValue = this_other_script.get_data()

    print(len(someValue))
```

in this_other_script.py:

```
def get_data():
    data = [1,2,3,4]
    return(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

in test.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import this_other_script
    someValue = this_other_script.get_data()

    print(len(someValue))
```

in this_other_script.py:

```
def get_data():
    data = [1,2,3,4]
    return(data)
```

Comment: Does `this_other_script.py` need the `if __name__ == '__main__':` or not? E.g. `if __name__ == '__main__':get_data()` where `def get_data():` function has been declared at the top?

Comment: If I included the `if __name__ == "__main__"` in this_other_script.py, it would not work. This is because, as you said, you are executing test.py with python. I found this explanation helpful (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: I think I misunderstood your comment, I will add an additional answer with what you said.